# how to show div one time each hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a div only 1 time each hour with a cookie. 
I try to use this js but this seems to work every day 1 time, and i want every hour 1 time.

what do i have to modify on this script?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
            //it is still within the day
            //hide the div
            $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').hide();
        } else {
            //either cookie already expired, or user never visit the site
            //create the cookie
            $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 1 });

            //and display the div
            $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Change your expiry to an hour, you have it set to 1 day. "Value can be a `Number` which will be interpreted as days from time of creation or a `Date` object"... from docs.

Comment: i do understand that. But how does the syntax look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Value can be a `Number` which will be interpreted as days from time of creation or a `Date` object"... from docs.

So you should be able to do something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
        //it is still within the day
        //hide the div
        $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').hide();
    } else {
        //either cookie already expired, or user never visit the site
        //create the cookie
        var date = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000); // thats an hour in ms
        $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: date });

        //and display the div
        $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').show();
    }
});
```